# "no enabled local indexes to search" when run rspec

Tags: rspec, thinking-sphinx

I'm trying to run some specs, but I'm receiving the error:

```
ThinkingSphinx::SphinxError:
       no enabled local indexes to search
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to set the username/password for test database in `config/database.yml`. After that, it works